# PHP passing a variable across pages

Tags: php, variables

I am having issues with a piece of code in Joomla. It may be something to do with the plugin that enables the  PHP but in case it isn't.

Page 1 has a form

```
<form action="/index.php/bridge" method="POST" name="postcode">
<div><input style="height: 50px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Postcode..." /> <input type="submit" value="Get Started today!" /></div></form>
```

The text you input becomes the variable I want to pass over

On Page 2

```
<?php echo "test";

 $postcode=1;
$poster=$_POST['postcode'];
echo $poster;
// You can place PHP like this

?>
```

Unfortunately, the postcode isn't echoed

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nothing else is the cause of this error, try naming the input you are sending over to `postcode`:

```
<form action="/index.php/bridge" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input style="height: 50px;"  name="postcode" type="text" "placeholder="Enter Your Postcode..." /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Get Started today!" />
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you are echoing `$_POST['postcode']` but you are not sending the same variable at the time of form submission from input attribute.

```
<form action="/index.php/bridge" method="POST" name="demoForm">
    <div>
        <input style="height: 50px;"  name="postcode" type="text" "placeholder="Enter Your Postcode..." /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Get Started today!" />
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="/index.php/bridge" method="POST">
<div>
    <input name="postcode" style="height: 50px;" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Postcode..." />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Started today!" />
</div>
```

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $poster = $_POST['postcode'];
}else{
    echo $poster = 1;
}
```

?>